# Reference to Integer and String

Tags: c++, object, reference, lvalue, rvalue

Can somebody explain me why in VC++ 12
string &s = string("this"); works but not int &d = int(10);
what operators are called while initializing a non const reference.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

False premise: `string &s = string("this");` is *not* valid C++. Lvalue references cannot bind to rvalues.

Comment: ok, now that was the reason I asked, should improve the question. It compiles for me in VC++ 12 compiler. I would like to know why?

Comment: @code_not_yet_complete: Because VC++ is not a C++ compiler, but the root of all evil :-) I'm very sorry for your loss. If you like to be industry-competitive (and employable) at C++, I recommend always cross-checking your code with a second compiler, e.g. Clang or GCC.

Comment: If a non-standard extension makes VC++ not a C++ compiler, then there are no C++ compilers.

Comment: @KerrekSB thanks for the reply. Can you probably tell me why it does not work for int ?